# Convert enum to material select in my component

Tags: angular, enums, angular-material-7

Now I have a some problem with enum.
I want make mat-select in component with enum values, but I'm not understand, how is possible.
I tried it, but but nothing worked

My ts component code

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
    
    import { Currency } from 'src/app/enums/CurrencyType';
    import { Edition } from 'src/app/enums/EditionType';
    import { Author } from 'src/app/models/Author';
    
    import { getAuthorsList } from 'src/app/store/author/author.actions';
    import { getAuthorsSelector } from 'src/app/store/author/author.selector';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-printing-edition-item',
      templateUrl: './printing-edition-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./printing-edition-item.component.css']
    })
    export class PrintingEditionItemComponent implements OnInit {
    
      type: Edition -- my enum
    
      constructor(private store: Store) {
       }
    }
```

my enum

```
export enum Edition{
  None = 0,
  Journal = 1,
  Newspaper = 2,
  Book = 3
}
```

my try in HTML:

```
     <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="type">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of type" value="item">type[item]</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```js
export class PrintingEditionItemComponent implements OnInit {

    type = Edition;
    keys: string[];
    
    constructor(private store: Store) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.keys = Objects.keys(this.type).filter(Number);
        this.selectedEdition = Edition.Foo;
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```xml
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="selectedEdition">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of keys" value="item">type[item]</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: keys must be string[] if you want use it`Objects.keys(this.type).filter(Number)`

Comment: Just fixed it :)

Comment: Maybe problem in enum? What you think about it ?

Comment: in the console i saw this ` ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: here its a project example, maybe this will help you out https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-enum-angular?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: check if the type is declared like that `type = Edition;`